# How to cover seams in plywood walls?

Tags: walls, sealing, plywood

I'm putting up a plywood wall in my garage workshop and have some unsightly seams; 1/8" or less gaps except around floor where I plan on installing baseboard anyway.  I've had to cut smaller segments of plywood to work around some workbenches installed by the previous owner so there's vertical and horizontal seams, if that matters.  I plan on painting the wall when finished but wondering what would be best to use to fill in/cover the seams before painting.

Comment: Why not painters' caulk?

Comment: My garage has plywood walls throughout; the builder added thin strips of 1-1/2" to cover all the seams. I think they're nailed in, but they might just be glued, too. They look nice, but they also make it annoying when I want to put something flush against the wall.

Comment: Painter's caulk is an option, I suppose, I just don't know if there's any caveats to that or if there is a better solution like Bondo or something.  Some of the seams are flush but I guess if the caulk sits on top instead of filling the gap then it might not be a problem.

I don't want to cover with trim/veneer for that same issue of hanging things on the wall.  This being a workshop, I want places to hang tools and not have trim getting in the way.

Comment: If you're opposed to covering it with a thin piece of something like screen molding, then I think caulk is going to be the best option.  You want some elasticity for a little movement (bondo might crack easily).

Comment: The previous owner of my house used drywall mud over the seams in the plywood wall in the garage.  It definitely cracked, so don't do that.  I vote for painters caulk or something flexible.  Run a finger over it to remove the bead if you want it to look smooth.

Comment: It's a garage shop, not the Louvre. And you're painting it, so painters caulk is not only the obvious solution, it's the right solution. That's already two steps closer to the Louvre than your average garage shop. Feel free to grain-fill the plywood and use umpteen coats of primer and sanding it back to obtain a flawless surface before the final coat of paint, then you can be 3 steps closer... Or you could skip all that and start screwing things to it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

The overwhelming consensus here seems to be standard painter's caulk so marking this as answered.  Thanks to all that responded.

Answer (score 0):

The most astheticaly(sp) pleasing way to cover gaps in a plywood wall with flush results is to glue up a veneer on the gaps.  caulking, silicone, anything else will be ugly, dirty, and eventually fall out.